# HttpRuntime.Cache has "2 versions" in my project

Tags: vb.net

So in my company we have this huge website project in Visual Basic. On this problem we have two parts involved, **the admin**, running at one port in local, and **the website**, running on another port.
The problem I have is that when I change a user's property in admin, it calls the function to save the user and adds the changes to the database. After that, we run a HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(key) and it is removed successfully. BUT when the website part tries to get the user from cache (before doing so from the database), it gets it successfully, even though it was removed previously. So my question is if this is a thing, if it's possible that even though using the same code, there are 2 different caches, I've done several tests and the cache is removed successfully from the admin part, it's definetly not a code problem.

Comment: Sure you are talking about VBA?

Comment: @FunThomas No, I meant vb.net, changing it now, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, that's how it works. If the same project has 2 or more applications running at the same time, each one has its own cache, even if they share the code that removes or adds things to cache. There is no mistake, the answer would be to create a function that clears the cache from the other applications.